# how to observe angularfireobject?

Tags: firebase, angularfire2

I am unable to read data from Firebase using angularfireobject.

This is  my code:

```
export class UserService {
    user: Observable<any>;
    constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    }
    public getUser($userId: string){
        this.db.object('users/'+$userId).valueChanges();
    } 
}
```

and in user.component.html

```
<h1>Welcome {{ (userService.user | async)?.name }}!</h1>
```

userService.user | json gives null.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not setting your `.user` Observable anywhere that I see and `.getUser()` is never called.

If you intend to show information on the current user you'll have to pull in authentication too:

```
export class UserService {
    user: Observable<any>;
    constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, private auth: AngularFireAuth) {
       this.user = auth.user.pipe(switchMap(user => 
         user ? db.object(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges() : of(null)
       ));
    }
}
```